# Problem with regular expression and preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I have a small problems with regex and php.
This is what i have:

> 8 Ball Script S Caps S S K

This is what i want:

> 8 Ball Script S Caps SSK

In short i need to correct every abrivations in the string dynamicly. wherever in the string that i can find something like "A B R I V", it needs to remove the spaces "ABRIV" without screwing with everything else in the string. So that i can have a string that is something like "H I, Hello F O O World, i have B A C O N" should become "HI, Hello FOO World, i have BACON".

This is my code so far:

```
$string = preg_replace("/(?<= )[A-Z](?![a-z]).(?![A-Za-z]+[a-z])/", '$0', $string);
```

Comment: `$string = str_replace("S S K", 'SSK', $string);` No need to use `preg_replace` on such a simple problem... ;)

Comment: Needs to be dynamic tho, the string that comes in can just as well be "L K D Text L F D More Text".

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. Why are the spaces between `S S` and `S K` removed, but the space between `S Caps` not?

Comment: @eldamar: Then you need to tell us the specifics, like what makes a group? Why shoul `S S K` be grouped as one, and not `S Caps`? (as @Bart said)

Comment: Sorry, end of the day request here and my english isn't so good. The reason is that S S K is a abbreviation and Caps is a word, so therefore i need all the abbrevations to be corrected globaly over the string. To be more specific i need ever capital letter that is followed by space, capital character and not lower character after that capital to remove the following space.

Comment: I think the idea is to group all 1-char words that are in caps.

Comment: `8 Ball Script S S K Caps S S K` = `8 Ball Script SSK Caps SSK`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
$s = preg_replace('~(?<![A-Za-z])([A-Z]) (?=[A-Z](?![A-Za-z]))~', '$1', $s);
```

**[see a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/6eC7O)**